# Haskell: Is there any object that is of every type, like `null` in Java?

Tags: haskell

In Java, with a little exception, `null` is of every type.  Is there a corresponding object like that in Haskell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

As in any sensible Turing-complete language, infinite loops can be given any type:

```
loop :: a
loop = loop
```

This (well, [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:undefined), or maybe [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error)) is occasionally useful as a temporary placeholder for as-yet-unimplemented functionality or as a signal to readers that we are in a dead branch for reasons that are too tedious to explain to the compiler. But it is generally not used at all analogously to the way `null` is typically used in Java code.

Normally to signal lack of a value when that's a sensible thing to do, one instead uses

```
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

which, while it can't be any type at all, can be the lack of any type at all.

Comment: @user2864740 Can you elaborate a little? Are you agreeing or objecting? If objecting, what are you objecting to, in particular?

Comment: I think user2864740 is just being a tad snarky about the use of the word "any" in your answer rather than "every".  Nit-picking semantics.

Comment: @Addem Hm. Perhaps. However, I believe I was quite careful. Although infinite loops can be given a type which corresponds to "every type" in Haskell, not all sensible Turing-complete languages have the kind of polymorphism necessary to do that. But even in languages that do not have the type `forall a. a`, you can usually construct an infinite loop of any (concrete) type.

Comment: Damn turing complete languages. You caught me there. Haven't been Haskell in a while and now I remember what I hated about it :D

Comment: Actually, to get a little bit deeper into that: We can construct any type from a `Void`. An infinite loop is just one example of that. The function `absurd :: Void -> a` shows how absurd this is.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `loop` and `undefined` can't be objects of unlifted types like `Int#`, so they don't inhabit every type. Though, this is like in Java: values of primitive types `int` and `double` can't be assigned to `null`.

Comment: @Shersh Surprise! `let x :: Int#; x = undefined in ()` is allowed, and throws an exception. `let f :: Int# -> Int#; f v = f v; x :: Int#; x = f 0# in ()` is allowed, and loops forever.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah, it makes sense now. I was testing differently in ghci, but now I see why it's working. `undefined` is lifted over unlifted types as well. Command `:info undefined` helps a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Technically yes, as Daniel Wagner's answer states.

However I would argue that "a value that can be used for every type" and "a value like Java's `null`" are actually very different requirements. Haskell does not have the latter. I think this is a good thing (as does Tony Hoare, who famously called his invention of null-references a [billion-dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions)).

Java-like `null` has no properties *except* that you can check whether a given reference is equal to it. Anything else you ask of it will blow up at runtime.

Haskell `undefined` (or `error "my bad"`, or `let x = x in x`, or `fromJust Nothing`, or any of the infinite ways of getting at it) has no properties at all. Anything you ask of it will blow up at runtime, **including** whether any given value is equal to it.

This is a crucial distinction because it makes it near-useless as a "missing" value. It's not possible to do the equivalent of `if (thing == null) { do_stuff_without_thing(); } else { do_stuff_with(thing); }` using `undefined` in place of `null` in Haskell. The only code that can safely handle a possibly-undefined value is code that just never inspects that value at all, and so you can only safely *pass* `undefined` to other code when you **know** that it won't be used in any way<sup>1</sup>.

Since we can't do "null pointer checks", in Haskell code we almost always use some type `T` (for arguments, variables, and return types) when we mean there **will** be a value of type `T`, and we use `Maybe T`<sup>2</sup> when we mean that there may or may not be a value of type `T`.

So Haskellers use `Nothing` roughly where Java programmers would use `null`, but `Nothing` is in practice very different from Haskell's version of a value that is of every type. `Nothing` can't be used on every type, only "`Maybe` types" - but there is a "`Maybe` version" of every type. The type distinction between `T` and `Maybe T` means that it's clear from the type whether you can omit a value, when you need to handle the possible absence of a value<sup>3</sup>, etc. In Java you're relying on the documentation being correct (and present) to get that knowledge.

---

<sup>1</sup> Laziness *does* mean that the "won't be inspected at all" situation can come up a lot more than it would in a strict language like Java, so sub-expressions that may-or-may-not be the bottom value are not that uncommon. But even their use is very different from Java's idioms around values that might be `null`.

<sup>2</sup> `Maybe` is a data-type with the definition `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`, whether the `Nothing` constructor contains no other information and the `Just` constructor just stores a single value of type `a`. So for a given type `T`, `Maybe T` adds an additional "might not be present" feature and nothing else to the base type `T`.

<sup>3</sup> And the Haskell version of handling possible absence is usually using combinators like `maybe` or `fromMaybe`, or pattern matching, all of which have the advantage over `if (thing == null)` that the compiler is aware of which part of the code is handling a missing value and which is handling the value.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the "real" mistake was lack of direct support for coproducts; compound types that contain **one of** their constituent parts. Structs, classes, etc, have provided straightforward support for product types (compound types that contain **all of** their constituent parts) for ages, but not their natural dual. Without coproducts it's hard to get by without something like `null` (unless you pile on enough other features that you can eventually simulate coproducts); you do need that "choice". When you've got coproducts then you can do things like `Maybe` in library code.

Comment: @WillNess It sure is. It's also not something Java makes nearly as clean as Haskell (or at least, not last time I was using it).

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for confirming. I was thinking about C/C++ actually, with its structs, classes, unions and yes null pointers. It's true *tagged* union is not a *language* construct in C, but it is very very close to it...

Comment: @WillNess Absolutely tagged unions are coproducts. I could debate whether C style unions count as "direct support for coproducts" though, since you have to manage the tag by hand. They're not really any more appealing than null pointers for handling "missing" values. But then C also isn't a language where it really makes sense to talk about a hypothetical version that had corproducts *instead of* nulls; there's no way you're going to get away from the concept of invalid pointers at that level.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No

It wouldn't be very type safe to have it. Maybe you can provide more information to your question to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Edit: Daniel Wagner is right. An infinite loop can be of every type.

Comment: Thanks, I think that basically answers my question--I'm not really trying to accomplish anything other than understand Haskell.  I ran into these "untyped" type declarations for functions, like `myFunc :: a -> a`.  Without knowing what `a` is, it seems like there are not many functions that could have this type declaration.  With a type declaration of `myFunc :: a -> b` it seems like nothing could have this type unless there were some object that is of every type.

Comment: Exactly. A function from of type `a -> b` can't be done in haskell. (Except for when it does. `unsafeCoerce` has exactly this type but we don't really use it) And as you can prove that there should be no function of type `a -> b` you can also prove that there should be exactly one function of type `a -> a` being the identity function.

Comment: For more info about this, this property that allows one to prove that the only function of type `a -> a` is the identity (and many other useful things about types!) is called [parametricity](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/09/22/parametricity-money-for-nothing-and-theorems-for-free/), which gives you so-called [free theorems](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf).  These theorems are also [naturality squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) from category theory.  Deep stuff here.  @Addem

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Yes.  But also no.**

While it's true that an infinite loop, aka `undefined` (which are identical in the [denotational semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics)), inhabits every type, it is usually sufficient to reason about programs as if these values didn't exist, as exhibited in the popular paper [Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/fast+loose.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

[Bottom](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom) inhabits every type in Haskell. It can be written explicitly as `undefined` in GHC.

Comment: Bottom isn't a type.

Comment: `Void` is bottom though.

Comment: @uwap ugh.  context.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with almost every other answer to this question.

```
loop :: a
loop = loop
```

does not define a value of any type. It does not even define a value.

```
loop :: a
```

is a *promise* to return a value of type `a`.

```
loop = loop
```

is an endless loop, so the *promise is broken*. Since `loop` never returns at all, it follows that it never returns a value of type `a`. So no, even technically, there is no `null` value in Haskell.

The closest thing to `null` is to use `Maybe`. With `Maybe` you have `Nothing`, and this is used in many contexts. It is also much more explicit.

A similar argument can be used for `undefined`. When you use `undefined` in a non-strict setting, you just have a thunk that will throw an error as soon as it is evaluated. But it will never give you a value of the promised type.

Haskell has a bottom type because it is unavoidable. Due to the halting problem, you can never prove that a function will actually return at all, so it is always possible to break promises. Just because someone promises to give you 100$, it does not mean that you will actually get it. He can always say "I didn't specify *when* you will get the money" or just refuse to keep the promise. The promise doesn't even prove that he has the money or that he would be able to provide it when asked about it.

---

An example from the Apple-world..

Objective C had a `null` value and it has been called `nil`. The newer Swift language switched to an `Optional` type, where `Optional<a>` can be abbreviated to `a?`. It behaves exactly like Haskells `Maybe` monad. Why did they do this? Maybe because of [Tony Hoare's apology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions). Maybe because Haskell was one of Swifts role-models.

Comment: I feel like The Joker, enjoying watching the world burn as I just set everyone into a holy war with my little question.  :)